# Empty Semicolon and Open Closed Curly Brace is Working

Tags: c#, console-application

I have console application project to support assigned to me, so I decide to conduct a code review in some class, and while I'm doing a code review I run to some line that contain just a semicolon and other line is a empty open-close curly brace, so my expectation is the compiler will throw an error, so I tried to run the console application but its working fine and no sign of error, I thought my compiler have a problem so I decide to reinstall it, but the console app is still working fine, so I decide to create a new method to test the semicolon and curly brace I also try to make a nested curly brace and with a `Console.WriteLine()` inside of it and its surprisingly working. Can anyone explain why this is happening or it's just me and my compiler?

```
static void TestMethod()
{
    ;
    { }
    ; { }
    { ; }
    {  };
    {
        {
            {
                {
                    {
                        {
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
                                Console.Read(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Relevant - [Sharp Regrets: Top 10 Worst C# Features](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867), by Eric Lippert.

Comment: @Kobi: He! Had the same thought :)

Comment: Likewise. :) Good article that - and I wholly agree with his comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Empty statements are allowed in C#.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> An empty statement is used when there are no operations to perform in
>   a context where a statement is required.
>
> Execution of an empty statement simply transfers control to the end
>   point of the statement. Thus, the end point of an empty statement is
>   reachable if the empty statement is reachable.

Also note [the definition of a block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664737%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). The statements inside the block are optional.

> A block consists of an optional statement-list (Section 8.2.1),
>   enclosed in braces. If the statement list is omitted, the block is
>   said to be empty.

Also see [comments about this "feature" from Eric Lippert](http://An%20empty%20statement%20is%20used%20when%20there%20are%20no%20operations%20to%20perform%20in%20a%20context%20where%20a%20statement%20is%20required.%20%20Execution%20of%20an%20empty%20statement%20simply%20transfers%20control%20to%20the%20end%20point%20of%20the%20statement.%20Thus,%20the%20end%20point%20of%20an%20empty%20statement%20is%20reachable%20if%20the%20empty%20statement%20is%20reachable.). (As mentioned by @Kobi in comments above.)

Note: People often cite examples such as this code as a reason to have an empty statement:

```
while (readNextChar() == ' ') // Skip spaces
    ;
```

Or the horrific:

```
while (readNextChar() == ' '); // Skip spaces
```

But personally I'd be happy if that had to be written as:

```
while (readNextChar() == ' ')
{ 
    // Skip spaces
}
```

However, this does illustrate the reason that you might need empty blocks (which I have no issue with).

Comment: Holy Molly! its a C# feature for real?

Comment: @Leonel It's also a C, C++ and Java feature. It exists in C# because in the old days they were trying to make C# more familiar to C/C++/Java programmers.